# How to configure Yarp.ReverseProxy HttpClient to use circuit breaker pattern

Tags: c#, .net-core, microservices, reverse-proxy, ms-yarp

We are using YARP Reverse proxy to access multiple services. But not requirement came where we need to implement circuit breaker and retry policy into that proxy service but I didn't found any reference online to achieve that.

```
 builder.Services.AddReverseProxy().LoadFromMemory().ConfigureHttpClient((context, handler) => {
            
        });
```

Here I can see configure client extension method is available not don't know How to configure that. Wants to configure the below code with Httpclient.

```
public class CircuitBreakerAndRetryDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IOptionsMonitor<AppSettings> _appSettings;
    private readonly IDisposable? _onChangeDisposable;
    private AsyncPolicyWrap _circuitBreakerAndRetryPolicy;
    public CircuitBreakerAndRetryDelegatingHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {
        _appSettings = appSettings;
        _onChangeDisposable = _appSettings.OnChange(x=> UpdateCircuitBreakerConfig());
        UpdateCircuitBreakerConfig();
    }

    private void UpdateCircuitBreakerConfig()
    {
        var circuitBreakerPolicy = Policy.Handle<HttpRequestException>()
                 .CircuitBreakerAsync(exceptionsAllowedBeforeBreaking: 3, durationOfBreak: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

        var retryPolicy = Policy.Handle<HttpRequestException>()
             .WaitAndRetryAsync(retryCount: 3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)));

        _circuitBreakerAndRetryPolicy = Policy.WrapAsync(circuitBreakerPolicy, retryPolicy);
    }
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await _circuitBreakerAndRetryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(
             async (cancellationToken) => await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken),
             cancellationToken
        );
    }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own delegating handlers by registering a custom `IForwarderHttpClientFactory` with DI. Deriving from the default `ForwarderHttpClientFactory` is the easiest option.

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IForwarderHttpClientFactory, MyClientFactory>();

internal sealed class MyClientFactory : ForwarderHttpClientFactory
{
    protected override HttpMessageHandler WrapHandler(ForwarderHttpClientContext context, HttpMessageHandler handler)
    {
        handler = new MyHandler(handler);

        return base.WrapHandler(context, handler);
    }
}
```